# Ubuntu not giving root permissions to file, works on debian

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, permissions, sudo

I'm trying to make a program a privileged program by doing the following:

1. sudo chown root
2. sudo chmod u+s

So now whenever someone runs , that user will be running that program with root privilege.
This works as expected in debian. However, when I try on Ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS on Google compute engine, it doesn't run with root privileges.

The program's permissions are as follows:
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root 
But for some reasons, whenever I run it on Ubuntu, it runs with the current users privilege. On debian, it runs as root (as outputted by ps -elf). Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

It's per security  measure on Ubuntu that the kernel just ignores the **suid** bit on all non-compiled executables ( Interpreted ).

It can be a serious security breach because anyone can change the script and populate it by anything he wants.

To do so ; knowing the risks ; You have to wrap your script with a non-interpreted language like **C**.

You can do ; create C file <path_to_to_your_prog>.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
int main() { 
    setuid( 0 );  
    system("<path_to_your_script>.sh" );
    return 0;
 }
```

Then compile it :

```
gcc <path_to_to_your_prog>.c -o 
 <path_to_the compiled_prog>
```

Then set the correct permissions :

```
chmod 4755   <path_to_the compiled_prog> # note the suid set here
chown root:root <path_to_the compiled_prog> <path_to_your_script>.sh
chmod 700 <path_to_your_script>.sh
```

Then run it :

```
<path_to_the_compiled_prog>
```

**Solution 2 :** *Preferred*

You can add a new group and make it as the secondary group of all the concerned users, then add it to your sudoers so they can run : `sudo <script_path>.sh` then set the correct permissions : `750` and onwership `root:<gid>` so they will be unable edit it.

Comment: Hi Reda, Thank you for your explanation.

However, I run into this case when I'm not running the chmod/chown commands through a script. Just as bash commands and the program still does not run with root privilege

Comment: Also, for what you are describing, are you assuming that the chmod/chown commands are done through a script? And for those scripts to actually take place I have to create a helper C program that runs the script?

Comment: Hi, chmod and chown are executed once and out of the script. Yes just follow the procedure to write the helper you don't have to change anything on your shell script. If this helped you you can make it as resolved ! Thanks

Comment: Thank you Reda.
But why is it that when I run chmod and chown as standalone bash commands, the program doesn't get root privilege?

If I just have a compiled program, prog1 and I do chown, chmod on it, it should be enough right?

Comment: chmod and chown commands are not meant for setting privileges but instead setting permissions and ownerships ; chown ( who can access what ) ; chmod ( who can read,execute,write to )

Comment: Right, sorry if I was vague in my terminology.
sudo chown root <program> - sets file ownership to root
sudo chmod u+s <program> - whoever runs this program runs with root privilege 

Since this is not being called from a shell script, I'm not sure why its not working

Comment: Yes as i have told you : when executing a script with siud it gets ignored by the kernel because this feature is dismissed for executables on almost all distributions due to security matter. And note that you can also customize your kernel to accept it. Hope it's clear

Comment: Right, but I'm not using a script, I'm just typing them as separate commands

Comment: me too i didnt used them in script and it will be the same result : script or not.

Comment: i think you did not get my answer, when saying that suid are not available it's not with chmod command but during the execution of your program.